# PowerShell out-file not working when variable has a "/" in filename

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that is running a GET and saving the results to file. the name of the file is using a variable from the GET URL however, then a forward slash exist "/". the file is not saved because it does not like the  forward slash.

```
$hostURL = "my_webserver"
$methType = "GET"
$api4 = "/sasl_logs/debug"
$txt | out-file ".\$api4.txt"
```

Results is a file called /sasl_logs/debug.txt or /sasl_logs_debug.txt. I have tried to get replace function working but i must be doing something wrong.

```
$api4.replace("//","_")
$api4.replace("/","_")
$api4.replace("\/","_")
```

Comment: What makes you think the `/` is the problem? What error are you getting? Does a `C:\sasl_logs` directory exist? Did you want a local `sasl_logs` directory? Do you not want a directory at all?

Comment: yes, my script runs a loop where i have multiple calls.

$api1 = "/diag"
$api2 = "/sasl_logs"
$api3 = "/sasl_logs/couchdb"
$api4 = "/sasl_logs/debug"

api1 works and i get a file name called "diag.txt", same with api2 "sasl_logs.txt" the rest run with no errors however they don't create a file and the only thing i see different is the api call that's used to create the out-file has a slash in the name. that's something that windows does not spport however, i cant figure out how to do a replace to change the / with a "." or "_".

Comment: That's not even remotely an answer to any of the questions I asked.

Comment: What makes you think the / is the problem? The slash is a issue as i am using winows and PS is trying to create a file called ./sasl_logs/debug.txt

Comment: That's a perfectly legal path as far as both Windows and powershell are concerned (Windows supports slashes in path names and has for quite a long time). Try a quick test: `mkdir sasl_logs/foo/bar` and see what you get. Your problem is likely that your path **starts** with a slash (and so roots to `C:\` or wherever) and that the `C:\sasl_logs` directory doesn't exist (and `Out-File` won't create it).

Comment: The replacement you want is `.replace("/", "_")` (or `$api4 -replace "/","_"`) but that's not the problem as such. That will "fix" the problem but you are fixing the wrong thing there.

Comment: your right its treating the /sasl_logs/ as a folder. if i create the folder manually it dumps the file within correctly. I was hoping to use a replace function to change the / to a _ so the file will end up like  ./sasl_logs_debug.txt... is that possible with the replace function?

Comment: I'm assuming you aren't setting `$api4` manually as in your snippet so you can't just change the line of code there? Yes, I gave the replace you want (sort of) in my previous comment. It will create a leading `_` though unless you strip that off.

Comment: yes this seems to be working

 `$txt | out-file ".\$api.txt".Replace("/","_")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is **not** the slash. Not in the way you think it is. Windows (and powershell) support `/` delimited path names just fine (as do many/most other Windows applications).

The problem here is that the path `/sasl_logs/debug` is being seen as an absolutel path (it starts with a slash) and so is being seen as `C:\sasl_logs\debug` and `Out-File` refuses to create the `sasl_logs` directory so it can put the `debug` file in that location.

Create the `C:\sasl_logs` directory and it should work correctly.

If you don't want that directory (or indeed any directory at all) and the `$api4` value isn't being set literally like that (so you can't just change the code) then you want something like what you were attempting.

```
$api4 = $api4.Substring(1) -replace "/","_"
```

`Substring` strips off the leading `/` and the `-replace` operator does the replacement. You could also use `$api4.Substring(1).Replace("/","_")` of course.

Comment: used the following and works perfect, thanks

 `$api = $api.Substring(1) -replace "/","_"`
 `$txt | out-file ".\$api.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

From your post and your comments, it *sounds* like you're ultimately asking how to successfully replace the "/" character...

```
$api4 = "/sasl_logs/debug"
$api4 = $api4.Replace("/","_")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is working, Thanks Etan Reisner

```
$txt | out-file ".\$api.txt".Replace("/","_")
```

Creates a file called

```
_sasl_logs_debug.txt
```

working on the leading _ now

Comment: See Etan's answer for .Substring(1) to handle the leading "_"